# Shiny conditional input panel with vector

Tags: javascript, r, vector, shiny, conditional-statements

I am looking to create a conditional panel in shiny that becomes active if the input that user selects from a list (i.e. selectInput function) belongs to another vector.

I am aware that the condition in the conditional panel is a javascript element, however I cannot make it work.

Can someone help?

Here is the UI part of the code under examination:

```
legs1 <- c("HOUSE","VILLA","ATTICO")

selectInput("strategy", "Strategy:", choices = df[,6]),

conditionalPanel(
           
          condition = 'input.strategy && input.strategy.indexOf("legs1") > -1',
                              
          textInput("Leg1", "Leg1",value = ""),
          textInput("Leg2","Leg2", value =""),
          
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to access the vector from within the condition it should work by using

```
condition = "input.strategy && ['HOUSE', 'VILLA', 'ATTICO'].indexOf(input.strategy) > -1"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the vector is way longer that 3 elements and it would be a bit inefficient doing this. I just included the first three to give an example, please let me know if you have ideas on how to put the vector inside the condition